# Fit plotly title in a column() and set its distance from the chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the `plotly` chart below which is included inside `column()`. I want to fit the `title` in a way that the second line to be left aligned and not in the middle as it is now and also I do not know hot to specify the distance between the chart and the `title`.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
x <- c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C')
y <- c(20, 14, 23)
text <- c('27% market share', '24% market share', '19% market share')
data <- data.frame(x, y, text)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
     column(4,
            plotlyOutput("plot"))
      ),
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'bar',
                   text = y, textposition = 'outside',
                   # rotate label
                   textangle = 90,
                   marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                                 line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5)))
    fig <- fig %>% layout(title =paste("Cumulative Uptake (%) of the first vaccine dose among adults (18+) in EU/EEA countries","as of 2021-04-05",sep="\n"),
                          titlefont = list(
                            
                            size = 12
                          ),
                          xaxis = list(fixedrange=T, title = ""),
                          yaxis = list(fixedrange=T,title = ""))
    
    fig
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I think might help is to use annotations to replace the second line. You can either use the annotation within the layout or like the example I provided using the add_annodations.
Unfortunately, the left adjust is not perfect (in my method), you need to change the xshift by the size of the image. You can play around with the add_annotations, for example, you can commend out the xanchor and xshift lines, the results will be the second line showing on top of the first column.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
x <- c('Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C')
y <- c(20, 14, 23)
text <- c('27% market share', '24% market share', '19% market share')
data <- data.frame(x, y, text)
plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'bar',
               text = y, textposition = 'outside',
               # rotate label
               textangle = 90,
               marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                             line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)', width = 1.5))) %>% 
  layout(title =paste("Cumulative Uptake (%) of the first vaccine dose among adults (18+) in EU/EEA countries"),
                      titlefont = list(
                        size = 12
                      ),
                      xaxis = list(fixedrange=T, title = ""),
                      yaxis = list(fixedrange=T, title = "",
                                   range = c(0, ceiling(max(data$y)*1.05))) ## Make the ylim a bit higher on top to avoid overlapping 
  ) %>%
  add_annotations(
    x = 0, y = ceiling(max(data$y)*1.05),
    text = "as of 2021-04-05",
    xanchor = "top",
    xshift = -50,
    showarrow = FALSE
  )
```

[Plotly Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRvqy.png)

The resulted plot looks like this when you lock the plotly object to a specific size. Since you are using shiny, you can use the height and width adjustment to force the plotly to be at a specific size, then the xshift amount can be locked to a specific number.